# Puma "Terminating timed out worker" after rendering HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I am new to AWS Beanstalk-Rails-Puma-Nginx.
After deploying my RAILS app to Beanstalk, all my api calls work fine, but HTML pages are causing error.

When opening my HTML page -

1. Nginx throws `502 Bad Gateway` error.
2. Puma log : 
   `Started GET "/admin" for 182.70.76.160 at 2016-04-22 05:13:19 +0000
   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
   [18858] ! Terminating timed out worker: 22913`
3. `var/app/current/production.log` is empty.

Read somewhere, that adding SSL could solve. Is it required to added SSL?

Please help! I am stuck!

**STATUS** : 
My assets were huge because of which it was killing itself. I was using a theme and removed all the unnecessary js, css and images.

Now, Puma doesn't terminate, but it doesnot compile assets. I had selected  Ruby as application type so it should do it for me, correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now I moved to EC2 as EBS issues weren't getting solved.
I had the same issue on EC2 but I could fix it as I access my machine.

Puma workers were timing out because my assets weren't precompiled.
Everytime I take a new build on server, I have to run the following :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 14):

Try setting worker timeout to a higher value in puma config. Default value is 60 seconds

`worker_timeout 100`

It is possible that you are creating more workers than the server could handle. Try decreasing the worker count or increasing the server capacity.

Comment: Hey Sebin! I tried this, but doesn't work. I just have 2 workers running so I don't think thats an issue.

Comment: Have you tried other log files and get more info? I am not aware of your deployment setup, but for me, I have puma access and error logs.

Comment: Yes! I have. But no leads. If you want more information about any logs, let me know.

Comment: If there is any error trace in any of the logs, you could update it in the question. Also I suggest you trying with one worker.

Comment: I tried with one worker but no luck. I am updating my question with the status.